# Wordpress: Blog in Child Theme isPaged() function one column less

Tags: wordpress

i have use a child theme and changed the blog templates in php. But i have the problem that i need in the isPaged() pages (page 2,3,...) of the blog theres still one post to much shown. Could you tell me in which file i can change the quantity of the posts in the isPaged pages...?

Best regards!

```
<?php astra_entry_before(); ?>

<article
    <?php elseif($postID == 0 && !is_paged()): ?>
<div
    <?php else: ?>
<article
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php
        echo astra_attr(
            'article-blog',
            array(
                'id'    => 'post-' . get_the_id(),
                'class' => join( ' ', get_post_class() ).' '.$marginPosition. ' '.$marginRightPosition.' '.$cssIsPaged,
            )
        );
        ?>
>
    <div class="article-holder <?php if( $postID == 0 && !is_paged() ) : ?>firstarticle<?php else: ?>standard-article<?php endif; ?>">

        <?php if( $postID == 0 && !is_paged() ) : ?>
            <div class="left">
                <div class="featured-image">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'featured-blog-size' ); ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="title"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php echo get_the_title( ); ?></a></h2></div>
                <div class="date"><?php echo get_the_date( 'F dS Y' ); ?></div>
                <div class="latest-banner"><span>latest article</span></div>
                <?php echo do_shortcode( '[molongui_author_box]' ); ?>
            </div>
        <?php else: ?>
        <div class="top">
            <div class="standard-image">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'standard-blog-size' ); ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="title"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php echo get_the_title( ); ?></a></h2></div>
            <?php echo do_shortcode( '[molongui_author_box]' ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php $articleType=''; if( $postID != 0 && !is_paged() ) : ?>
</article>
    <?php elseif($postID == 0 && !is_paged()): ?>
</div><!-- #post-## -->
    <?php else: ?>
        </article>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php astra_entry_after(); ?>
```

I have found the following code, but it destroys the page:

```
function my_custom_query( $query ) { if ( is_paged() ) {   $query->set( 'posts_per_page',9);} }
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_query' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The function for posts per page need to be in the functions.php:

```
function be_change_event_posts_per_page( $wp_query ) {

    if( $wp_query->is_main_query() && is_paged() ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'posts_per_page', '9' );
    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'be_change_event_posts_per_page' );
``
```